# React Native Installing Cocoapods dependencies error

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, react-native-ios

Whenever I try to create an app I get this error.
[First Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Te9I1.png)

So I followed what it says, go to the ios folder, and do pod install there also got a huge error.

[Second Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wr5CF.jpg)

[Third Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghjpX.jpg)

Since the error was big I've only pasted two images

Then, I opened my fresh terminal and checked that whether cocoapods is installed or not and I found that I've already cocoapods through brew.

I also updated brew even I tried installing Xcode CLI tools and I found it is already installed.

[The last thing tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzuMy.png)

Actually, I've got a doubt, do I need to have Xcode ide because I'm just getting started with react-native, so I've no idea. But the thing is I've got a Mac but an Android phone and actually tried to run through the Android emulator and it was actually working because I've Android studio already, but I want to know what that error is and how to resolve it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you should install xcode and follow this steps as well https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup select mac and ios

Comment: @anthonywillismuñoz thanks for the guidance, I'll be following you but one more doubt is that in docs it is written that 'sudo gem install cocoapods' but I've already got this through homebrew. So, do I need to do that?

Comment: You can skip it if you already got it installed just make sure you have last version

Comment: okay thanks @anthonywillismuñoz